# Passing data from AJAX to PHP with POST method without using <form> element

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm having a "Undefined index" while passing values from ajax to php without using a form.

Here are my codes:

```js
function sendDatasToPhp() {
    var id = <? php echo json_encode($id); ?> ;
    var otherId = <? php echo json_encode($_SESSION['id']); ?> ;

      $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "send_data_to_php.php",
        data: "id=" + id + "&otherId=" + otherId,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
          alert("Datas are being transfered");
        }
      })
    }
```

```html
<div>
  <label class="send_datas" onclick="sendDatasToPhp();">Send datas to php</label>
</div>
```

Assuming that `$id` is already initialized and `$_SESSION['id']` has already a value. The problem is that the two indices are undefined once transferred to the php file. How can I fix these?

Comment: Look at the HTML source code you are generating from PHP. Is it correct?

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Console. Are there any errors?

Comment: Open the developer tools in your browser. Look at the Network tab. Can you see the request to `send_data_to_php.php`? Does it have the correct values for `id` and `otherId`.

Comment: No errors in the console, only the Undefined index in the php file.

Comment: I checked the values and they are the same.

Comment: @Quentin I checked the Network tab and the values are the same, except that there is an extra one.

Comment: Please paste piece of PHP code where you retrieve values from `$_POST`

Comment: @Zudwa
You mean the php variable to send? It is just a `$id` and `$_SESSION['id']` that have values already.

Comment: @Zange-chan I mean inside **send_data_to_php.php**. At the moment I see that you are using different variable names for order ID (**d** in uppercase in one place, lowercase in the other). Probably same error in php file

Comment: @Zudwa 
Oh, that's supposed to be `otherId`, I'm just giving the logic though. The php file variables are the same the ajax that is being send.

Comment: Please read [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: @Quentin
I made it work. I use `GET` method instead of `POST`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the `GET` method instead of `POST` and I made it work.

Answer (score 0):

In your html add to hidden inputs:

```
<input type="hidden" id="id" value="<?= $id; ?>" >
<input type="hidden" id="otherId" value="<?= $_SESSION['id']; ?>" >
```

then your script need to be like:

```
function sendDatasToPhp() {
    var id = $('$id').val();
    var otherId = $('$otherId').val();

    var data = {
       id: id,
       otherId:, otherId
    };
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "send_data_to_php.php",
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        success: function() {
           alert("Datas are being transfered");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I have no problem with the php variables. I changed the method to `GET` and it works.

Answer (score -1):

What is json_encode for? It's not needed.
change `method` to `type`.
There's one closing parenthesis after `$_SESSION['id']`
success function has an input argument `success: function(data) { alert(data); }`

Comment: Its passing php variables to ajax since it doesn't work if raw php variable is being send.

Comment: "What is json_encode for?" — It escapes special characters safely when passing data from PHP to JSON.

Comment: "change method to type" — `method` is the current standard. `type` is old.

Comment: "There's one closing parenthesis after $_SESSION['id']" — That might be relevant.

Comment: "success function has an input argument success" — There's no point in defining an argument name if you aren't going to use it.

Answer (score -1):

Data attribute in $.ajax function should be in below format.

```
data: { id: id, otherId: otherID },
```

edit: Can you print the exact error that you are getting?

Comment: Not like this: `data: { "id": id, "otherId": otherID },` ?

Comment: @Zange-chan — The using strings instead of identifiers makes no difference.

Comment: While it is best practise to let jQuery generate the URL encoded string, it's unlikely that the hacky approached used to construct it by hand in the question is the problem.